# window.event.x in ie 11 in compatibility view giving wrong results

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I’m using this code to get the  coordinate of the mouse.

```
MyObject.prototype._mouseMove = function (e) {
    var el,x;
    el = (e) ? e.target : window.event.srcElement;
    if (el.tagName == 'NOBR') { el = el.parentNode; }
    x = (e) ? e.pageX : window.event.x + this._eBody.scrollLeft;
    …
}
```

but with IE11 when using **compatibility view** I get wrong X coordinate.

Did anyone have any clue or go around method?

BTW

I’m using this tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8; charset=utf-8" />
```

But need to add the page to compatibility view manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solutions

I’m using the window.event.**clientX** instead of the window.event.**x** and it's working

```
x = (e) ? e.pageX : window.event.clientX + this._eBody.scrollLeft;
```